# How to trigger a script at a given time in the Timeline?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timeline

I would like to know if it is possible to trigger a script at a specific time in the Unity Timeline.
I don't want it to be triggered for the duration of the application, but only after a certain time.
Indeed, with this script the user will be able to type on the touch screen as soon as the script is triggered.
My problem is that this script is launched from the start of the application!
Should we handle this directly in the Timeline or should I modify my script?
Thank you for your precious help

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SelectObject : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("escape"))
            Application.Quit();

        TapSelect();
    }

    void TapSelect()
    {
        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
                RaycastHit hit;
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
                {
                    
                    Application.OpenURL("https://www.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't get it, you want to trigger a method after a certain time of running the application?

Answer (score 2):

What you need depends on your UnityVersion, from 2019.1 and above UnityTimeline introduces [Signals](https://blogs.unity3d.com/es/2019/05/21/how-to-use-timeline-signals/), which is what you need (Unity has his own [videotutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v14PdlcJnnA) teaching how they work).

But if you are using an older version of Unity (<2019.1) you need to write your own CustomPlayables (there are some [DefaultPlayables](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/default-playables-95266?_ga=2.166638713.653081719.1604487894-1751818090.1485189056) to check on the assetstore, and [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSrcQJHDUT4) really helps me out to understand how they work).

Other good Timeline reference: https://blogs.unity3d.com/es/2018/09/05/extending-timeline-a-practical-guide/

Comment: Thanks buddy for your help.
I actually tried using these signals, but I'm no expert. in fact i have not succeeded in linking my script with a signal i have placed.
Can a little help be?

Comment: i have a screenshot to show you so that to unterstand you but i can't post in this comment...have you a mail?

Comment: @nki7ki76 You're welcome. I think you can upload a link with the image (at least one). Appart from uploading the image, try to define "I have not succeed in linking my script", maybe some log error?

Comment: .Actually, I don't know what function should I apply as a reaction to this signal

Comment: @nki7ki76 seems like a different question, "how to disable touch input". And you can solve this with a boolean (like allowInput) and using it on a condition block like (if allowInput && Input.touches...).

Comment: Here are the methods that appear but I don't know which one to choose:
* Bool enabled
* String name
* BoolRuninEditMode
* StringTag
* Bool use GUILayout
* BroadCast Message (string)
* CancelInvoke (string)
* CancelInvoke ()
* SendMessage (string)
* SendMessageUpwards (string)
* StopAll Coroutines ()
* StopCoroutines (string)